# Self Lookup restriction not respected for a lookup field

Tags: apex, dmlexception

I have 2 lookup fields to Opportunity in Opportunity Object. Parent Opportunity and Ultimate Parent Opportunity. I cannot update the parent to itself, which gives the expected error below

> You cannot set a hierarchy field Parent Opportunity to point to itself or a child record. Either edit one of the child records to not refer to this record, or do not set the field on this record.

However, I can update the Ultimate Parent Opportunity to itself. Why?

I also tried to update the Ultimate Parent Opportunity programmatically but gives a system dml exception error.  FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, Below code. Not able to understand why it allowed me to do manually and why the Field Integrity Exception is coming up when updating via code.

```
  List<Opportunity> optyList = [Select Id, Name,ParentOpportunity__c, UltimateParentOpportunity__c 
                            from Opportunity 
                            LIMIT 10];              

  for(Opportunity opp: optyList){
     opp.UltimateParentOpportunity__c = opp.Id;
  }

   update optyList;

    System.debug(' optyList after-- '+optyList);
```

Comment: You cannot set lookup to itself. Perhaps, you set it to the opportunity that has the same name as the one you're editing.

Comment: I checked. Its the same opportunity.